# Align <div> to left inside a <li>?

Tags: css, html

I am working on the footer of this website and I would like to add the Skype chat option to the contact. It's an script inside a div. I have tried to arrange it to the left like the other li elements inside the ul with no luck, check out this screenshot :

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0791c43g8d

The Fiddle  :   jsfiddle.net/mCuVq

The HTML :

```
<h4>Suggestions, offers?</h4>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Send us a mail</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Send us a message on Facebook</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="SkypeButton">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                Skype.ui({
                    "name" : "chat",
                    "element" : "SkypeButton",
                    "participants" : ["xxx"],
                    "imageSize" : 32
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS for the mid ul :

```
footer .wrapper .column.midlist ul li {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0 0 0px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;

/*  background: url(img/arrowright2.png) left 6px no-repeat;/*/
    text-align:left;
}


footer .wrapper .column.midlist ul li a:hover {
    color: #e56038;
}

footer .wrapper .column.rightlist ul li {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
```

Comment: Could you create it on jsffidle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mCuVq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code responsible for your problem was vertical-align code created by the Skype JavaScript, and had to be overridden.

Change `<div class="SkypeButton">` to `<div id="SkypeButton">` and Add this to your css :

```
#SkypeButton_paraElement a img { margin:0 !important; 
                                  vertical-align:0 !important }
```

<kbd>**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/mCuVq/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Wow ! I was going crazy with it, didn't know that ! That's a serious answer, thank you so much !

Comment: Glad to help!. If you are very observant, and you try to see it through with **inspect element in chrome** or other browsers, you can make it with ease.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the below css. Check it if it works for you:

```
footer .wrapper .column.rightlist ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work ... it makes the whole list go extreme left but there is still an space between the list left border and the image ...